# Where do I put the JavaScript files in Hexo?

Tags: javascript, themes, hexo

Where do I put the JavaScript files so I can extend Hexo using its helper function?

```
 hexo.extend.helper.register('my-hexo-commadnd', myJavascriptFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `scripts` folder under your themes.

Imagine you have the following folder structure:

```
- My Hexo Theme
  - languages
  - layout
  - source
  - template
  - any other folder
  - scripts
```

Just add the `scripts` folder, as shown above. Every JavaScript file is going to be picked up by Hexo.